Swift UIView inner views shrink on Scroll
Is there any default behaviour that would cause UIViews to "shrink" when they scroll below the header of the parent view scroller?
I have autoresizesSubviews = false set

Can you share more code? What is the current state of your view? What is the desired behavior? People cannot guess what is going on with a single line of code.
